# How to uninstall an app from one administrator id, but it should not be uninstalled for everybody?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I installed BlueStacks for all users. But now I want to uninstall it from the administrator user, while keeping things unchanged for all the other users. Is this possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

See, Apps are installed in two ways. 1: For all users, 2: For a Specific user. When apps are Install for all users, It is located somewhere in C: drive, usually `C:\Program Files`, from where it is accessible to all users. When installed for a specific user, it is installed in `%appdata%`, so that it is accessible to only a user. In your case, your App, ie Bluestacks, is installed for all users, ie in the C: drive Therefore, it's not possible to "Delete bluestacks for a particular user. That would need a reinstall only for users.
You might think here that you could simply move the folder to `%appdata%`, it would save you some trouble, but would cause you far more trouble eventually. dO nOt try this...

If you want to, you can Remove the Program from the list of Installed programs, like so:

1. Open `regedit` from search or from Run
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`
3. Locate your program under the "Folder" (Key), Right-click and delete.

This would remove your program from list of installed program, Windows wouldn't treat that program as installed for that user. However, the app can still be opened from that user directly or using shortcuts. If you want to prevent access to that app too, You must stop access from the GP editor:

1. Run `gpedit.msc`
2. Go to `User Configuration > “Administrative Templates > System`
3. Open the policy `Don’t run specified Windows applications`
4. Click `enabled`, then `Show` list of disabled application
5. Add the program to the list, for example `Bluestacks.exe`